# Spark persist function in reusing dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, caching, dataset, persistence

Let's say I created dataset by different transformations (join, map and etc) and saved it to table A in hbase. Now I want to save the same dataset to another tables in hbase with selecting specific columns. In this case, should I use persist function after saving to table A? Or if I use only select function, it doesn't matter?

For example:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = //computing dataset by different transformations
//save ds to table A in hbase

ds.persist();

Dataset<Row> ds2 = ds.select(col("X"));
//save ds2 to table B in hbase

Dataset<Row> ds3 = ds.select(col("Y"),col("Z"));
//save ds3 to table C in hbase

ds.unpersist();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala is lazy, in this case that means that all transformations will be redone for every action if you do not persist the data. Hence, if computing the dataset `ds`

```
Dataset<Row> ds = //computing dataset by different transformations
```

takes a long time, then it would absolutly be advantageous to persist the data. For best effect, I would recommend it is done before the first save (the save to `table A`). In the persiting is done after that, all the reading of data and transformations will be done twice.

Note that you should not use `unpersist()` until all actions on the dataset and the subsequent datasets are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Dataset<Row> ds = //computing dataset by different transformations
ds.persist();    
//save ds to table A in hbase

Dataset<Row> ds2 = ds.select(col("X"));
//save ds2 to table B in hbase

Dataset<Row> ds3 = ds.select(col("Y"),col("Z"));
//save ds3 to table C in hbase

ds.unpersist();
```

This way you can persist everything, and then keep saving different sets of columns to different tables.